# How to get data-slick-index id and used it to go in specific slide

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

How can I use the `data-slick-index` id in my slider? What I'm trying to do is when I try to click the button 2016, the slide will changed into 2016 content something like that. I tried to use `data-slick-index: 1` to each button with different index's but its not working.

```
<div class="center slider">
    <div class="slide-col">year 2016</div>
    <div class="slide-col">year 2017</div>
    <div class="slide-col">year 2018</div>
</div>
<div class="slick-nav">
    <button data-slick-index= "1">2016</button>
    <button data-slick-index= "2">2017</button>
    <button data-slick-index= "3">2018</button>
</div>
```

Comment: already changed it to "=" but anyway still it doesn't work. do you know how to get the data-slick-index id and use it as a button to navigate specific slide I want?

Comment: If you have a click handler on the button, you can grab the index with either `this.dataset.slickIndex` or `$(this).data('slickIndex')`, but how to use that with slick slider, I'm not familiar with the plugin.